# How to click on a label with puppeteer

Tags: html, node.js, puppeteer

I have this label in html:

```
<label for="tamanhoIndisponivel">
```

> The label I want to click on is on this page
> https://www.nike.com.br/chuteira-nike-premier-2-sala-unissex-153-169-171-309321

**Note:**

I already have all my code ready, I just need a piece of code so I can click on this element
How can I click on the label with puppeteer?

Comment: Please share a [mcve] showing the code you've written so far showing the problem (you can remove the unnecessary stuff in both the Puppeteer code as well as the target HTML you're working with). Which label do you want to click on and what's wrong with your current attempt? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the code to click then this should be enough in your case if you have the correct locator

```
 await (await page.waitForSelector('label[for=tamanhoIndisponivel]')).click()
```